# How to fix O2 sensor system?

Tags: honda, accord, o2-sensor

After getting some type of P116x primary heated O2 sensor error (I forget the exact error), I replaced the primary O2 sensor on my car. (I had to make a bracket for the electrical connector because the lead on the new sensor was, for some reason, not long enough to reach the bracket holding the connector.) However, soon thereafter I was getting some new errors:

> P1167: Primary Heated O2 sensor heater system malfunction
>   P1165: Primary Heated O2 sensor circuit range malfunction
>   P1149: Primary Heated O2 sensor circuit range malfunction

I do not know what the problem is, and I can't find anything beyond the nominal meaning of the error codes in the Honda Accord Haynes Repair Manual I have.

I would guess it is some other part of the O2 sensor system was the issue, but I wouldn't have any idea where to begin with troubleshooting the issue.

What is the actual cause of the problem here, and how can I fix it?

The car in question is a 2000 Honda Accord, with a F23A4 engine (2.3L SOHC 16-valve VTEC four-cylinder)

Answer (score 1):

check the part number on the new sensor. The shorter connector pigtail and new 02 sensor circuit codes appearing after the repair sound strange to me. Couldn't hurt to double check at least

Comment: This seems very likely the issue.